# why doesn't it add 1 to recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

**Javascript**

---

why does startNum++ which adds upto 7 in first execution doesn't make startNum argument 7 in function call inside function itself?

```
 function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
 
    if(startNum===endNum){
       return [startNum];
    }else if(startNum<endNum){
       return [startNum];
       startNum++;
       rangeOfNumbers(startNum,endNum);
     }
  };
  rangeOfNumbers(6, 9);
```

Comment: `return` *stops a function*. The code after a `return` is never going to be executed.

Comment: `return` exits the function. The recursive call is never executed.

Comment: Else if branch:  If this works as I think, it never gets to the startNum++ increment because it returns first.

Comment: You are returning startNum for both conditions. Try removing the `return [startNum]` in the else if block and do `return rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum)`. Should get you closer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines after `return` are unreachable

```
 function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
 
    if(startNum===endNum){
       return [startNum];
    }else if(startNum<endNum){
       return [startNum];
       startNum++;                   //this line is unreachable
       rangeOfNumbers(startNum,endNum);
     }
  };
```

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller.

Comment: once return works it's gonna exit the function. with understanding that i will move forward for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the result of the `rangeOfNumbers`:

```js
  function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
 
    if(startNum===endNum){
       return [startNum];
    }else if(startNum<endNum){
       startNum++;
       return rangeOfNumbers(startNum,endNum);
     }
  };
  console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 9));
```